# Page template with custom html fields inside a content

Tags: customization, pages, page-template, forms

I'm writing a custom page template and I want to do something like this:
after typing tag inside page content, for example [custom-email-form] I want to place inside the content some html5 email form.

How to achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that when the page is rendered your `[custom-email-form]` is replaced with html? That's just a [custom shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). Just create a plug-in that registers the shortcode and then outputs its content when called.